# When looping through a list and printing, user can type in the python shell

Tags: python, optimization

I'm making an ASCII based python RPG for a project. The game features a grid system that allows for the players, enemies etc. to move around. Whenever the lines of code (below) are executed in the default python shell, the printed grid lines and cells can be altered by the user.

Is there anyway that the looping and printing of the grid can be optimized so that the grid prints out instantly and the user cannot change the grid by typing on the keyboard?

#### Code

```
def gridPrint():
    # print cell nums
    print("x  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 ")
    length = len("x  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 ")

    # access rows
    for x in grid:

        #print row nums
        print(str(x), end="")

        #print cells
        for y in grid[x]:
            for z in grid[x][y]:
                if (len(str(x)) == 1) and (y == 1):
                    print(grid[x][y][z], end="")
                else:
                    print(grid[x][y][z], end="")

        print("")
    print("*" * length)

gridPrint()
```

Also the project will be marked using the default python shell so no other shells or interpreters or IDEs will be used by the teacher. ¯*(ツ)*/¯

EDIT - This code is not quite what my grid looks like the actual project but it should help to illustrate my problem, which is the speed in which the grid prints out.

Comment: Looks like you need some non-buffered input and interrupt system

Comment: I tried to execute your code into a Python shell, got `TypeError`, can you confirm?

Comment: No worries, just try to not flood comments too much :p

Comment: i've just edited the code so that it runs and prints a "grid" although the grid isnt exactly what I got in my project. @Arount

Comment: could you please explain @iBug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since you have some issues with your code I made a new grid system mockup so we can work on something.

But before the code, the solution:

---

You can use [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html)

You just need to set first parameter to an empty string so `getpass()` will not prompt `Password:`:

```
userinput = getpass.getpass('')
```

---

Now the mockup:

*Please not I'm not proud of this code, it's kind of dirty, don't do that at home please.*

```
import getpass

# Game over flag
end_game = False
# Define 6 x 6 grid
grid = [['#' for y in range(0, 6)] for i in range(0, 6)]

def print_grid(grid):
    ''' Print grid in stdout. '''
    print('-'* ((6*4) + 1))
    for line in grid:
        print('| {} |'.format(' | '.join(line)))
        print('|-{}-|'.format('-'* ((6*4) - 3)))
    # Yea, userinput is just printed like this here
    # This is a mock..
    userinput = getpass.getpass('')
    print('==> {}'.format(userinput))

# Main game control loop
while end_game is False:
    print_grid(grid)
```

Comment: This seems to work but in curiosity, what does getpass actually do?

Comment: I gave you the link to the doc :) ([`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html))